# How to calculate the redis database size?

Tags: database, redis

**Redis** redis database size, how we can calculate size in mb. Suppose there are 1000 record in redis database then how we we can calculate its size in mb

Comment: redis-cli info Memory

Comment: I would look at this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844672/how-do-i-view-my-redis-database-current-size